# How can I use one database with multiple django servers?

Tags: python, django

I saw lots of information about using multiple databases with one server but I wasn't able to find contents about sharing one database with multiple servers.

Using Micro Service Architectures, If I define a database and models in a django server, named Account, How can I use the database and models in Account server from another server named like Post??

What I'm thinking is to write same models.py in both servers and use the django commands `--fake`

Then, type these commands

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

and in another server

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate --fake`

I'm not sure if this would work and I wonder whether there is any good ways.

Comment: If you have a shared database then you can provide the `--database` argument to the migrate command and there shouldn't be any issue

Comment: @lain Shelvington I think the way you said is to use multiple databases in one server.  However, what I want is use one database with multiple servers.

Comment: Do you want multiple apps to use the exact same database or have a few shared tables?

Comment: @rurp exact sane database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, I have the same case that I have 2 Django servers and 1 database.

I did that I run on server 1

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and on server 2 I just run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I did not run migrate commands on server 2

Now if there is any change on model then I run `makemigrations` command on both servers and `migrate` command on any of one server. I am using only one database

Comment: On the second thought, Is there any need to make migrations? though I won't migrate.

Comment: Thats for the safe side if you forgot that in future that on which server you run makemigrations command. If you run makemigrations on both server then there will be no issue if you forget.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this is the best approach, but if you want two separate Django projects to use the same database you could probably create the first like normal then, in the second project, copy over all of the models.py and migration files. Django creates a database table behind the scenes to track which migrations have been applied, so as long as the apps, models, and migration files are identical in the second app it should work without having to fake any migrations.

That said, this sounds like a mess to maintain going forward. I think what I would do is create a single Django project that talks to the database, then create an API in that first project that all other apps can interface with to communicate with the database. That way you avoid duplicating code or having to worry about keeping multiple projects in sync.

Comment: Oh, What you want to say is to use one main database project and to make other servers communicate with the database by using API of main database project. Right?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. With Django you can install Django REST Framework which makes it easy to setup basic views for your models, which then can be customized as needed. So only the original project would need to speak directly to the database.

Answer (score 3):

When using additional Django servers with the same database that is already managed by the initial Django server, the tables don't need to be managed by the additional servers.

So you can add into the `Meta` for the models that `managed = False` and Django will not need to touch them, but can still use them. You will need to copy your models across to the additional servers, or use `inspectdb` (see below).

```
from django.db import models

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='db', primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'example_table'
```

You will probably need to state the name of the table being referenced in the `Meta` as well, otherwise Django may generate a name that doesn't match the database.

You can even cut down the models when using them unmanaged.
It's not necessary to declare all the fields, just the ones you're using.

You can also use `python manage.py inspectdb` to automatically generate unmanaged models for all the tables in your database, saving time and ensuring the model fields conform to the actual database setup.

This is detailed in the documentation:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#managed
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb